# How to round only bottom 2 corners with drawRoundRect in Jetpack Compose Canvas

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As the title says, I am just trying to figure out how can I round only the bottom 2 corners of the round rect.

```
drawScope.drawRoundRect(
                topLeft = Offset(0f,0f),
                size = Size(100f,100f),
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 10f, y = 10f),
                color = boxPaint.color
            )
```

This is my current code, which rounds all corners.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like with `drawRoundRect` you only can setup left or right corner radius.

When you find that the Canvas API is missing something, you can draw almost anything using `Path` - it has much more flexible API.

```kotlin
val cornerRadius = CornerRadius(10f, 10f)
val path = Path().apply {
    addRoundRect(
        RoundRect(
            rect = Rect(
                offset = Offset(0f, 0f),
                size = Size(100f, 100f),
            ),
            bottomLeft = cornerRadius,
            bottomRight = cornerRadius,
        )
    )
}
drawPath(path, color = Color.Red)
```

Comment: Brilliant! They almost thought of everything